# Thermal average of fermionic operators in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body, greens-functions

Consider the following expression of a thermal average involving fermionic operators
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\nu, \nu', \sigma, \sigma'}\langle c_{\nu,\sigma}^{\dagger}(t)c_{\nu',\sigma'}\rangle,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\langle A \rangle = \frac{1}{Z}\sum_{n} \langle n|A|n\rangle e^{-\beta E_n}.
\end{equation}

In the book "Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics", it is stated
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\nu, \nu', \sigma, \sigma'}\langle c_{\nu,\sigma}^{\dagger}(t)c_{\nu',\sigma'}\rangle = \sum_{\nu,\sigma} \langle c_{\nu,\sigma}^{\dagger}(t)c_{\nu, \sigma}\rangle.
\end{equation}

Without the time-dependence, this is clear to me (by making use of the orthogonality in the number occupation representation), but why is this also true for a creation operator given by $c_{\nu,\sigma}^{\dagger}(t)=e^{iHt}c_{\nu,\sigma}e^{-iHt}$ ?

Comment: I would guess, because the operators are a special choice creating/destroying eigenstates of $H$, so the time evolution does only induce a phase. To get a definitive answer to your question, please provide a full reference to the book (title, author, edition, year, publisher) and where in the book (page, chapter, equation number) the claim is made.

Comment: I found this in "Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics" (Oxford Graduate Texts, version of 2016) by Bruus and Flensberg and in particular, I am talking about p. 163, Eq. (10.50).

Comment: @SebastianRiese: Could you find the equation in the book? I am still not sure how this is justified.